# WordPress database error log yet Blog loads and looks fine

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, plesk

I'm trying to hunt down an error that keeps appearing in my Plesk log for a Wordpress install I have. It uses the theme `Colornews` and I'm able to load the blog and it appears to look as expected. The error shows in the log as this:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: WordPress database error Table
>   'blog_database.wp_commentsINNER' doesn't exist for query
>   \n\t\t\t\t\tSELECT wpcoms.*, wpposts.ID, wpposts.comment_count,
>   wpposts.post_title\n\t\t\t\t\tFROM (\n\t\t\t\t\t\tSELECT
>   *,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t@num := if(@post_id = comment_post_ID, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t@post_id := comment_post_ID as
>   cpID\n\t\t\t\t\t\tFROM wp_commentsINNER JOIN wp_posts
>   wpposts\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tON (comment_post_ID =
>   wpposts.ID\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND (wpposts.post_status = 'publish' OR
>   wpposts.post_status = 'inherit') \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND
>   wpposts.post_password = '' AND wpposts.post_type = 'post'
>   )\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWHERE comment_approved = 1 AND comment_type = ''
>   ORDER BY comment_post_ID DESC, comment_ID DESC \n\t\t\t\t\t) as
>   wpcoms\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWHERE wpcoms.row_number <= 3\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tORDER
>   BY wpcoms.comment_date DESC\n\t\t\t\t\t\tLIMIT 3 made by
>   require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   include('/themes/colornews/index.php'), get_sidebar, locate_template,
>   load_template, require_once('/themes/colornews/sidebar.php'),
>   dynamic_sidebar, W...\n'

Its a long shot but wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction to fix the error.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. There's an error in the SQL query:

```
wp_commentsINNER
```

the space is missing between the table name and the `INNER`. Locate where that query is executed and fix it.

Comment: Looks like it's being generated from a comment widget.

Comment: Turns out the widget did have an SQL error. It used to work just fine so im assuming it was broken on an update. Thanks!